# Can I add a directory as prefix for my configuration files in Nginx?

Tags: debian, nginx

I have a development environment with a simple Debian image whilst I also use a Jetware EC2 optimised Debian image for my staging environment.

The Jetware filesystem is mounted under the `/jet`, hence I have slight changes between my nginx.conf et vhost files, ex:

`pid /run/nginx/nginx.pid;`
vs
`pid /jet/run/nginx/nginx.pid;`

Or also `include /jet/etc/nginx/mime.types;` vs  `include /jet/etc/nginx/mime.types;`

Is there a *server_root* directive of sort that I could add to my nginx.conf configuration, to keep the changes between files minimal ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the approach (initiating a "$filesystem_root_dir" variable at the top of the file and assigning it one value per configuration) is:

- Not allowed (it throws the fatal: `nginx: [emerg] "set" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1`)
- discouraged by the Nginx team:

```
Variables should not be used as template macros. Variables are evaluated in the run-time during the processing of each request, so they are rather costly compared to plain static configuration. Using variables to store static strings is also a bad idea. Instead, a macro expansion and "include" directives should be used to generate configs more easily and it can be done with the external tools, e.g. sed + make or any other common template mechanism.
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html

I thought about a template generator but the cost way outweight the gains, so I'll either keep the files slighlty different moving forward.